# 0x0 empty GraphicsPlaceholder array

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am trying to obtain the handle of a TextBox in a GUI window.

[image]

```
>> SliderTool
>> h = findobj('Tag', 'xText')
h = 
  0x0 empty GraphicsPlaceholder array.
>>
```

Why is `h` an empty array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default (at least in R2015b) the GUI figure's property `HandleVisibility` is set to `callback` this prevents `findobj` to find the handle of the uicontrols even if  the `HandleVisibility` of the uicontrol is set to `on`.

To solve your problem, you have to set the `HandleVisibility` property of the `figure` to `on` too.

The following picture shows how to set the `HandleVisibility` of the GUI figure and the result.

[image]

Comment: The image shows the Property Inspector of the EditText (the uicontrol) as indicated by the title of the figure. It is needed to "double click" in a point of the GUI not containing any uicontrol in order to be able to set the property of the "figure" of the GUI

Comment: Actually, at least on R2015b it worsk. I've updated the answer with a screenshot showing the result.